# Problems with malloc, memory leaks in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, malloc

I am having a tough time figuring out what is going wrong in my program. I am trying to create a linked list by creating nodes in the createNode function then adding them to the head of the list with addNode. The programs fails when I try to create a node and I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "list.h"

struct listnode {
    int line;
   char *word;
   struct lnode *next;
};


struct listnode* createNode (char* word, int line) {
  int strlen1 = strlen(word)+1;
    struct lnode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
    node->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen1);
    strcpy(node->word,word);
    node->word[strlen1] = '\0';
    node->next = NULL;
    node->line = line;
    return node;
}


void addNode (struct listnode** head, struct listnode* node) {
    if ((*head)==NULL){
    head = &node;
    }
    else if((*head)->next!=NULL){
        struct lnode *temp = *head;
        node->next = *head;
    }else if(*head!=NULL&&(*head)->next==NULL){
        (*head->next) = node;
    }
    }
```

Running the program through valgrind produces the following errors:

```
==14661== Command: ./testlist
==14661== 
==14661== Invalid write of size 1
==14661==    at 0x4006E3: createNode (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==    by 0x40091C: main (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==  Address 0x51dc0a6 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==14661==    at 0x4C2AF5D: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64  linux.so)
==14661==    by 0x4006AF: createNode (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==    by 0x40091C: main (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661== 
==14661== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14661==    at 0x40071C: addNode (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==    by 0x400933: main (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14661==    at 0x4008E8: main (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661== 
==14661== Invalid read of size 8
==14661==    at 0x40071C: addNode (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==    by 0x400933: main (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==14661== 
==14661== 
==14661== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==14661==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==14661==    at 0x40071C: addNode (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==    by 0x400933: main (in /u/data/u95/testprogs/testlist)
==14661==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==14661==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==14661==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==14661==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==14661==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

I'm new to C and I'm not sure why these errors are being thrown. Could someone please help?

Comment: You don't need to add the terminator to the string in `createNode`, it's done automatically by `strcpy`.

Comment: Show us the code in `main`. Do you have atleast 1 node which is on stack?

Comment: In the function `addNode`, the statement `head = &node;` is assigning the address of local variable `node` to the the `head`. `node` is local to the function `addNode`

Comment: Also note that the operator `->` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the unary operator `*`. So the expression `*head->next` doesn't do what you expect it to (it's equal to `*(head->next)`). I'm surprised you don't get a _lot_ of warnings compiling your code.

Comment: `node->word[strlen1] = '\0';` is actually a bug because it writes beyond the end of the allocated buffer.

Comment: **Read** the messages! They say exactly what you are doing wrong, and tell you which function is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a definition for `lnode`.  Is it the same as `listnode`?

`addNode`  sets the head element incorrectly and doesn't find the tail of long lists correctly.  It should be something like

```
void addNode(struct listnode** head, struct listnode* node) {
    if ((*head)==NULL){
        *head = node;
    }
    else {
        struct listnode* tail = *head;
        while (tail->next != NULL) {
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        tail->next = node;
    }
}
```

You were missing an assignment of `*head` for an empty list.  Setting the value of `head` changed the local pointer but not the caller's pointer.  For longer lists, you need to iterate through all members to find the tail.

This may fix your `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` errors.  If it doesn't, you'll need to show us the code which calls `addNode`.

`createNode` could simplify allocation/initialisation of `word` to

```
node->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
strcpy(node->word,word);
```

You don't need to set a null terminator - `strcpy` will copy this for you.  And, as noted by William Pursell, this is actually an important change as it avoids you writing beyond the end of the string.  This will fix your `Invalid write of size 1` errors.

Answer (score 1):

The following is guaranteed to be wrong:

```
node->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen1);
...
node->word[strlen1] = '\0';
```

You allocate strlen1 bytes for word, so you probably meant:

```
node->word[strlen1 - 1] = '\0';
```

Note that you do not even need to write a null byte, since `strcpy` does that for you.  It's not clear what other errors are in the code, and it's not really worth looking until you fix this one.